# from simpletransformers.language_modeling import LanguageModelingModel NOT WORKING

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, simpletransformers

I have installed simpletransformers with success. Why is it not working? A big thank you in advance.

```
from simpletransformers.language_modeling import LanguageModelingModel
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-eb4f4fd6459f> in <module>
----> 1 from simpletransformers.language_modeling import LanguageModelingModel

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpletransformers\language_modeling\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from simpletransformers.config.model_args import LanguageModelingArgs
      2 from simpletransformers.language_modeling.language_modeling_model import LanguageModelingModel

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simpletransformers\config\model_args.py in <module>
      6 import warnings
      7 
----> 8 from torch.utils.data import Dataset
      9 
     10 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question with "pip install torch" and updated the Microsoft C++ reading software. :)))